# Having some trouble with Grease Pencil

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, grease-pencil, error

I'm not entirely sure whats happening but every time I try to use Grease pencil on my mesh it comes out all scrambled[image] and weird. Posting pic for more information,.

Comment: It is possible that this is connected to the add-on, and not directly a problem in Blender. Try disable SpeedRetopo and see if you can use the grease pencil as intended. If it is connected to the working of the add-on  I suggest you rephrase your question... or ask the creator directly: http://www.pitiwazou.com/contact/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently I had bsurfases added twice. I just had to delete one of the installations. Now everything works fine